# PHAsset sharing the image(UIImage) with UIActivitiViewController lose metadata (Exif and etc)

Tags: uiimage, metadata, uiactivityviewcontroller, phasset

In my project I share image and video phasset with UIActivityViewController

But for the image, when I share 3.0MB image with **UIActivityViewController** then it grows over 6.0MB and lose metadata.

In my source

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                                                  options:options
                                            resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                                                if (completion)
                                                    completion(imageData);
                                            }];
```

when I check **imageData** it still has metadata but if I convert it to UIImage and try to share it then it lost its metadata (Exif and etc...) and sized up.

Is there a way to share the original file with metadata (= No data lose)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.

1. Save NSData image to file with **writeToFile**
2. Share image as NSUrl

then no metadata lose.

Comment: Hi Kim, share the video has the same problem losing the metadata. Do you have any idea to not lose the metadata for video file sharing ?

Comment: @srjohnhuang Maybe this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196661/exporting-video-using-photokit-phasset-gives-different-video-file-every-time/38427082#38427082

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for the hint. It seems Apple will break the camera roll's metadata while sharing it directly from camera roll. The current solution just like what you mentioned in the link, to copy the video to app's document folder.