# iOS requestExportSessionForVideo exports video without metadata

Tags: ios, avasset, phasset

I use **requestExportSessionForVideo** for exporting video located in iPhone to document directory.

I gave options and exportpreset to export the exactly same video saved in camera roll.

But the result is little bit different. When I compare it with beyond compare it has difference **especially in metadata**.

How could I export video which exactly same as the video in camera roll?

**FYI**

I gave a exportPreset option as **AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough**
and for PHVideoRequestOptions, I gave **PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic** or **PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat** but didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear but I think exporting video from the camera roll does not guarantee fetching same video in every time. So I copied the video from camera roll to my document folder with url (avurlasset.URL) by [NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:] then it copies the same video in every time. For now it is my final solution.

**SOLVED**

Please have a look "[Exporting video using PhotoKit (PHAsset) gives different video file every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196661/exporting-video-using-photokit-phasset-gives-different-video-file-every-time/38427082?noredirect=1#comment64656655_38427082)"